# Angular 2 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello i am learning angular2, so i came up with this error no idea why. This is simple, please help me to resolve. I have two components, try to use selector from other components in template of first component. Component is imported so i don't know why i get error.

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'playlist' is not a known element:
```

first component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductListComponent } from './product.component';
import { Video } from './video';
import { PlaylistComponent } from './playlist.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
  directives: [PlaylistComponent]

})
export class AppComponent {

  head =ProductListComponent.MAIN
  videos = Array<Video>;

  constructor(){
    this.video = new Video(1,'youtube','axaEfeaS','Ovo je mnogo lepa deskripcija');
  }
}
```

second component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'playlist',
  templateUrl: 'app/playlist.component.html',

})
export class PlaylistComponent {

}

html app.component file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<div><playlist></playlist></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Help needed tnx

Comment: Though it would not fix your issue, I just wanted to say your `app.component.html` doesn't need to have `html,head,body`  tag there

Comment: I don't think you need the html, head, and body tags, as those are taken care of by index.html. Remove all of that from your app.component.html file, and remove the div tags enclosing the <playlist></playlist> tags. All you need are the playlist tags. What are the results after that?

Comment: alert alert not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on version 2.0.0, the directives property in @Component is obsolete.  It was available through much of beta, but recently removed in the RCs.

You need to look at the most recent documentation.  You'll need to implement an ngModule to pass in that component.